# Bash script: Store w3m dump into variable

Tags: bash, w3m

How to store w3m dump result into a variable in a bash script? The result I got by w3m dump is
    C: randomIP randomPORT randomUSERNAME randomPASSWORD
I want to cut "C:" and store everything else into variables so I can add it into a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can store any bash command output in this manner:-

```
var=$(command) # replace command by w3m dump command
#Later you can replace first occurring of C: by sed
var=$(echo $var | sed s/^C://)
```

Now `var` variable will consist of dump without "C:".

Comment: Now I have only the text I want, but how to assign randomIP randomPORT randomUSERNAME randomPASSWORD to variables? Thanks!

Comment: I got it to work with IFS=" "
set $var
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
echo $4

Comment: yeah you can `cut` command to separate a line. You can use some thing like this:- `echo 'randomIP randomPORT randomUSERNAME randomPASSWORD' | cut -d' ' f1` for getting `randomIP`. Similarly `f2` for 2nd argument and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
<your command> | read useless var1 var2 var3 var4
```

As explained in [man read](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html), `read` will (big surprise!) read a line on standard input (hence the pipe) and assign the given variables one by one using the IFS (by default the space character) as a delimiter in the input.

So in your example, `useless` will be assigned to "C:"; `var1` to "randomIP"; ...

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11741816)

Comment: Quite true. Besides, I realize that my here string was pointless here, a pipe will suffice. I added some explanations but my solution is straightforward now. Thanks.